# How can I avoid using too many ifs in this case?

Tags: php, optimization

This is working but dont seems  the right way to code

I have no idea about what to do

```
foreach ($data as $tag) {
    if ($tag==1) echo "<a onclick=\"window.location.href='/buscatag/1'\">Coméda</a>,\n";
    if ($tag==2) echo "<a onclick=\"window.location.href='/buscatag/2'\">Ecchi</a>,\n";
    if ($tag==3) echo "<a onclick=\"window.location.href='/buscatag/3'\">Peitos grandes</a>,\n";
    if ($tag==4) echo "<a onclick=\"window.location.href='/buscatag/4'\">Nudez</a>,\n";
    if ($tag==5) echo "<a onclick=\"window.location.href='/buscatag/5'\">Seinen</a>,\n";
    if ($tag==6) echo "<a onclick=\"window.location.href='/buscatag/6'\">Violência<a/>,\n";
    if ($tag==7) echo "<a onclick=\"window.location.href='/buscatag/7'\">Vida Cotidiana</a>,\n";
    if ($tag==8) echo "<a onclick=\"window.location.href='/buscatag/8'\">Harém</>,\n";
    if ($tag==9) echo "<a onclick=\"window.location.href='/buscatag/9'\">Ação</a>,\n";
    if ($tag==10) echo "<a onclick=\"window.location.href='/buscatag/10'\">Shonen</a>,\n";
    if ($tag==11) echo "<a onclick=\"window.location.href='/buscatag/11'\">Super Poderes</a>,\n";
    if ($tag==12) echo "<a onclick=\"window.location.href='/buscatag/12'\">Aventura</a>,\n";
    if ($tag==13) echo "<a onclick=\"window.location.href='/buscatag/13'\">Fantasia</a>,\n";
    if ($tag==14) echo "<a onclick=\"window.location.href='/buscatag/14'\">Loli</a>,\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in code you can immediately put the number into a tag

try

```
$names = ['name1', 'name2'...];

foreach ($data as $tag) {
   echo sprintf("<a onclick=\"window.location.href='/buscatag/%s'\">%s</a>,\n", $tag, $names[$tag-1]);
}
```

Comment: Actually better for this situation than what I had proposed

Comment: And this solves what? How do you distinct `Comeda`, `Ecchi` etc?

Comment: Your names array is 0 indexed and the tags start from 1. It will not match up

Answer (score 4):

```
// Define $lookup as 
$lookup = [1 => 'Coméda', 2 => 'Ecchi',]; // etc
// Note the relation between key and value

foreach ($data as $tag) {
    echo "<a onclick=\"window.location.href='/buscatag/{$tag}'\">" . $lookup[$tag] . "</a>,\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're going to test the same variable many times you can use a switch to make it better:

```
foreach ($data as $tag) {
    switch ($tag) {
        case 1:
            echo "<a onclick=\"window.location.href='/buscatag/1'\">Coméda</a>,\n";
            break;
        case 2:
            echo "<a onclick=\"window.location.href='/buscatag/2'\">Ecchi</a>,\n";
            break;
    }
}
```